# Sort My Computer drive list by label

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

How can I sort the drive list under 'My Computer' by drive label. Currently it is sorted by drive letter.

```
label2 (A:)
label5 (C:)
label3 (E:)
label1 (F:)
etc.
```

I would like them to appear sorted by their label and still retain the drive letter information.

```
label1 (F:)
label2 (A:)
label3 (E:)
label5 (C:)
etc.
```

Is this possible with explorer?

Comment: [Yep](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/192936-drive-sorted-drive-letter.html) it is.

Comment: @Ramhound Can you clarify your link. The first method hides the drive letter - which is not a valid solution. I have tried the second method and it does not appear to work as the grouping works on ranges of letters - try it to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Open Explorer and click "View" from the menu bar, slide down to "sort by" then select sort by name.

[image]

If you do not see then menu bar, click Organize>Layout, tick menu bar.

[image]

Comment: This is what I expect to work. However in my case it does not. It's interesting to note that in your screenshot your drives are not sorted by label. They are sorted in reverse order by drive letter, `G: F: C:`. The external devices are also sorted by letter.